# Difference between https vs https://www

Tags: apache, web, https, load-balancing

We are dealing with some dns configurations, would like to know the difference between
 https ://mydoman.com and https ://www.mydomain.com. The reason for the question is, https ://www.mydomain.com works fine but  https ://mydoman.com doesn't.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
M

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `www` host record (www.mydomain.com) for your domain is the only record that has a valid destination.

Your `@` host record (mydomain.com) points nowhere valid, so the domain name cannot be resolved.

There really is no difference *functionality-wise*. The user can access the site no matter if you choose to use either or both. Most sites use both in some way (e.g. resolving the `www` record to the `@` record or vice versa).

`https://` is a protocol, and has no effect on DNS.